# PHONE_CALL permission not working in Dexter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-phone-call

I have implemented [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) in my app. It is work fine for CAMERA,EXTERNAL STORAGE and INTERNAL STORAGE permission. I want to call with PHONE_CALL permission with [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter). When i call intent for phone call like this:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + strNum));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

then `startActivity` shows warning `Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException less... (Ctrl+F1)`

I don't understand that i have implement [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) then why `startActivity` want self permission?

Answer (score 2):

For API 23+ you should check for permission as:

```
if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + strNum));
    startActivity(callIntent):   
}
```

`Intent.ACTION_CALL intent`, which requires a permission, namely the **android.permission.CALL_PHONE** one. But for sdk>=23 you need to check in runtime with `Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE`. It is for targetedsdkversion 23 and above.

If you lower your targetedsdkversion below 23 then you don't need this persmission and `Intent.ACTION_CALL` will work fine.

Comment: I know that. But i have used Dexter library for permission model. Then why i have to check Self permission and another thing is that if i use  `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` instead of `Intent.ACTION_CALL` then its not shows warning. So i don't understand what should i do?

Comment: Check my edited answer.. Intent.ACTION_DIAL will not make a call directly ..it brings up the dialer with the number you have inserted..That's why Intent.ACTION_DIAL doesn't need the permission as user confirms to make a call manually.....

Comment: I want to check PHONE_CALL permission by only Dexter. Is it possible or not? and if possible then how?

Comment: yes , you can lower your targetedsdkversion to below 23.. but for sdk>23 you should check it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  For me, my justification was showing when I tried to make a call.  I added the manifest tag:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Not sure why I had to do this in addition to using Dexter runtime checking, but it solved my issue.